# accepting and saving the data entered into input field (email) using django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a newbie currently learning how to work with django.
I rendered a static homepage with an email input field for a project. The field is supposed to get inputs from folks that would want to be on my waitlist for the project when it's ready.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l6P6.png)
I'm confused about how to capture this data and store it in my database and now i'm stuck.
I tried creating an app within my project called Waitlist with a model class(Waitlist). This class has just one attribute "email".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNXmG.png).

would really appreciate some kind assistance.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you must add name field to your HTML input field firstly and wrap it in a form field. Like this

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email_field" />
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

And after you click the button, you expect the request.POST to have "email_field:xxx@gmail.com" something like this. So in the view, you must get this value from the request.POST and save it as a new abject like below

```
email_input=request.POST.get("email_field")
WaitList.objects.create(email=email_input)
```

Comment: hi, i applied this function-based technique, but i get a "csrf token missing" error. even after i added to the the form

Comment: okay you're right! sorry i forgot to add the token... you should put {% csrf_token %} right under <form method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

@devocip- If you want to make your life easier and write least amount of code to get your project up and running then use django generic views. They literally do most of the heavy lifting for you instead of the normal function based view.For your case, to capture and save the data in the database, you will need CreateView.

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-based-generic-views-django-create-retrieve-update-delete/#createview
```